# Cannot install MiKTeX in 2022 on a new PC under Windows 10 or Windows 11

Tags: miktex, windows, editors

I have been installing various versions of MiKTeX for nearly 10 years without any trouble at all…  until three months ago, when I built a new PC.

```
Hardware: Asus ROG MAXIMUS X11 HERO – wi-fi motherboard.
Intel socket 1200 10th generation i7 core processor.
32GB DIMM 4 RAM.
```

Upgraded Asus Bios to latest version: 2403 x64.

Setup: set Bios to optimized default (F5).
Installed Windows 10, Home Edition, on SATA 250GB ssd hard drive, using Windows 10.iso burned to DVD disk.
Used a new partition of 250GB on ssd; refreshed and formatted.
After installation…  used Windows Power Shell(admin), ran defrag: giving 5%, and then \scannow: found errors but all were fixed.
Shut PC down multiple times.

Downloaded the file: “basic-miktex-21.12-x64.exe” from the official MiKTeX website.
In admin mode, tried to install MiKTeX to newly created directory:

```
c:\program files\MiKTeX 2.9
```

Tried as single-user and multi-user, adding packages “on the fly” or “ask me”, etc
I have also tried using the suggested default directory: c:\users…
Tried with defender both enabled and disabled.
Followed all instructions using the MiKTeX Console to update packages.
After each repeat, I used Uninstaller 7 to clean up thoroughly.

I also performed some of the above steps while opting to use Windows 11.
Editor used: Technic Center 2.0

I must have tried more than 40 times without success.

Most frequently, the file latex.exe does not appear where I believe it should: in

```
c:\program files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
```

Sometimes, a new directory c:\program files\MIKTEX is created and contains some, but not all the files/folders.

I can install all my other regular programs: Microsoft 365, Abobe Illustrator, Nero Burning Rom, WinZip...  first attempt with no problem whatsoever.

Could my downloaded file: basic-miktex-21.12-x64 be corrupt?  How could I test this possibility?
Very comfortable with the Technic Center/MiKTeX combination when it is working; really don’t want to change.

Comment: well you are not saying what doesn't work when you install. But generally: The miktex issue tracker is here https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues (but they will need more info about your errors too). And you can always try to install texlive instead. It shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: Running a .tex file under Technic Center gives the error...  latex.exe not found.  It is not possible to complete any of the questions posed by the setup wizard.

Comment: I emphasize that, in eight or nine years previously, installing failed once in perhaps ten occasions.  If I tried now - correctly following all the advice - I know it would fail.

Comment: Don't try in texniccenter. Try on the command line first, and check if the path variable is correctly set.

Comment: I regret I do not have the expertise to do that, but surely the outcome would only confirm there is a problem?

Comment: perhaps. But it would you give some idea *where*  the problem is. It could be simply a faulty texniccenter installation. Go to the windows explorer, type `cmd` into the address bar. That should open a command line. Then type there `where pdftex`  and hit enter. Report back what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134071/discussion-between-keith77777-and-ulrike-fischer).

Comment: I am surprised to find that, after more than 400 views, not a single viewer has come forward and declared: "I have had the same (bad) experience."  That does suggest there is something fundamentally wrong with my setup. What more can one do other than follow precisely the install instructions?

Comment: Until now you have given no proof that the installation failed. It could be simply a wrong configuration of texniccenter. So learn to use the command line and to run pdflatex from there. Then you will also get sensible error messages.

Comment: File locked by another...  2022-02-16 13:42:51,966Z INFO  pdflatex - this process (9228) started by 'cmd' with command line: pdflatex math_text.div
2022-02-16 13:42:51,966Z INFO  pdflat
2022-02-16 13:42:51,966Z FATAL pdflatex.core - Permission denied: path="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/lock\package-manager.lock"

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher The above was after removing all traces of MiKTeX and TechnicCenter from my PC and then reinstalling MiKTeX for one user.

Comment: You should really stop to deinstall and reinstall all the time. How should anyone (including yourself) be able to investigate if you constantly change the system? How can you now be sure that none of the previous installation left some trace which now interfere? Close everything miktex related. Restart your computer and check in the task manager that really nothing miktex related run. Then try again a simple pdflatex compilation.

Comment: If it still errors: Make a complete description (including rights and paths) how you installed miktex. Then describe how you try to test it and which error you get. And then open an issue at the miktex github.

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher I would think that re-installing Windows 10 and then installing MiKTeX in the presence of no other programs is a more stringent and reproducible test than what you are suggesting in your comment above - and that is exactly what I've done. It would help if you could assure me that reinstalling Windows does, in fact, ensure that all traces of installed programs are removed.

Comment: Just for my understanding: When you write, you tried installing in admin mode, did you do it: a) as admin from Power Shell, b) logged in as non-admin AND executed as admin (right mouse context menue), c) logged in as admin AND executed the installer? // With bad luck this might make a difference ...

Comment: @MS-SPO I'll answer as best I can...  I sign in to Windows as an administrator. I then run all programs by right-clicking - "run as administrator".  Is that not the optimum choice?  As a matter of fact, I have not done that in the past, when I had more or less 100% success.  What is the logic behind your suspicion?

Comment: As I indicated, to rule out this potential source of error. Only because 3 ways are namend the same, they actually can differ. Small chance, but you never know. So did you try the othe 2 as well? Again, jsut to rule out ...

Comment: Two more things: 1) When you are logged in as admin, you shouldn't need to use the context menu: you ARE admin. // 2) Do you have and tried installing older versions, including the portable ones, especially those which worked in the past? Though it's not a systematic approach it might give you further clues. // And: @UlrikeFischer already made very good proposals to obtain more focused information. Perhaps you can team up locally or by video with a "experienced command line hacker" ?

Comment: @keith77777 I never installed miktex as admin. I'm logged in as normal user and then install it without admin rights "only for me" (single user mode).  I never give applications more rights than they need.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your comments.  I will investigate and list my findings as soon as possible.

Comment: Following further trials today, I think MS-PRO is correct – it is almost certainly about administrator privileges.
Most of us - especially those installing programs – are administrators.
A correct response to the requirement given in the next comment would, I believe, provide an answer to my question – and I’m sure be very useful to others.

Comment: I am an administrator using Windows 10 with all the latest updates.
I wish to install the latest basic-miktex for use as a single user in a folder c:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 using paper size A4, and adding packages “on the fly”.
Starting from the command line status c:\Users\keith, what exactly are the four of five or so commands that would successfully produce a MiKTeX console?
In particular, where in the folder structure should the file basic-mikex-21.12-x64.exe be placed?

Comment: Maybe it's because you have a special character in the installation path?  Is everything in English or do you have something like c:\joão ?

Comment: @MarioS.E. No, all is in English.

Answer (score 1):

I have given-up trying to install MiKTeX to a directory of my choice. Instead, I allow MiKTeX to use the default directory - which I think is untidy - and it works perfectly every time, both in Windows 10 and in Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

General note, to all users of recent Windows (10+):

If your system refuses to install MiKTeX, The first place to ask is at the MiKTeX site. If nobody else is having the same problem, and you are sure that the problem is not self-caused, you have a brute-force alternative:

Enable the Linux sub-system. There, you can install TeXlive, from the package manager of whatever Linux you use (probably Ubuntu). You should be able to add extra packages via the `tlmgr` command-line program, and build using command-line `pdflatex` or `lualatex` or whatever is appropriate.

The last time I checked this, long ago on Windows 10, It was possible to install VNC software into Linux, and a VNC viewer into Windows. That enables you to see the Linux GUI in Windows. Essentailly, you run two systems simultaneously, and they talk to each other via VNC. Find the "how to" on other web sites.

Just remember that there is a difference between line endings in Windows, and in Linux. There are various programs that can do the conversion, if necessary.